# Cannot Create React App Using create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I am trying to create a react app with

```
create-react-app
```

but it get the following error

```
Creating a new React app in /home/freduah/react-jumia-clone/react-jumia-clone.
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ct-assign":"^2.0.0","'
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/freduah/.npm/_logs/2020-10-26T11_32_34_616Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting react-jumia-clone/ from /home/freduah/react-jumia-clone
Done.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing your cache using `npm cache clean --force`?

Comment: i tried but now i'm getting the error below 

`npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...bdih\nC8acONhBiiT69vZ'`

Answer (score 0):

Check your version of npm and other
or,

Try deleting cache in the terminal as :

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Comment: i tried but now i'm getting the error below

`npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...bdih\nC8acONhBiiT69vZ'`